# Updating values of an old dataframe with a new dataframe using multiple columns and with different sizes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to updated a dataframe with another dataframe. They have the same columns, but have different sizes.

```
old_df = pd.DataFrame({"Primary_ID":[ID1,ID1,ID1,ID2,ID2,ID2,ID3,ID3],"Secondary_ID":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], "Value":[100,200,300,400,5000,600,700,8000]})

new_df = pd.DataFrame({"Primary_ID":[ID3,ID2],"Secondary_ID":[8,5],"Value":[800,500]})
```

I was trying to update using `old_df.update(new_df)`, but this will get the indices udpated in a wrong way since they have different sizes (so we have to match the exact values for all the columns except the column called "Value" in both dataframes, and updated it that way)

I was also looping through each row on both old and new dataframe and try to match the values that way, but thats not optimial as these dataframes have quite the size to them

Any advice?

Comment: what is the expected output? `update` relies on the index so you'd need to set your IDs as temporary index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `update` directly, a better approach might be to [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to align the DataFrames and set the new values, then [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to restore the old values:

```
out = new_df.merge(old_df[['Primary_ID', 'Secondary_ID']],
                   on=['Primary_ID', 'Secondary_ID'], how='right'
                   ).combine_first(old_df)
```

Output:

```
  Primary_ID  Secondary_ID  Value
0        ID1             1  100.0
1        ID1             2  200.0
2        ID1             3  300.0
3        ID2             4  400.0
4        ID2             5  500.0
5        ID2             6  600.0
6        ID3             7  700.0
7        ID3             8  800.0
```

Comment: Awesome , thats it! I was trying to do something with merge as well, but wasn't aware of the `combine_first` method there! 

I changed it a bit just so that we can use all the columns except the last one in case someone needs something more dynamic:

`out = filtered_new_df.merge(old_df_copy[list(old_df_copy.columns)[:-1]], on=list(old_df_copy.columns)[:-1], how='right').combine_first(old_df_copy)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get indices that have to be updated by merging the 2 dataframes and searching for not empty values in `new_df.Value` like this:

```
merged_df = old_df \
    .merge(new_df, on=["Primary_ID", "Secondary_ID"], how="left")

old_df["Value"].update(
    merged["Value_y"][~merged["Value_y"].isna()].astype(int)
)
```

I added `.astype(int)` because pandas converts columns with NaNs to float. If you actually have float values in real task, remove that part.